# What is the ip address command equivalent of the default output of the ifconfig command?

Tags: linux, ifconfig

The default output of the `ifconfig` command on GNU+LINUX displays only active and up network interfaces while the default output of the `ip address` command (which can be shortened as `ip a` ) shows all network interfaces including inactive and down interfaces.

What is the `ip address` command equivalent to show only active and up network interfaces like the default output of the `ifconfig` command?

Answer (score 8):

`ip address` shows all IPv4 (`inet`), IPv6 (`inet6`), and link-level (like `link/ether` for ethernet interfaces) addresses by default, while `ifconfig` without `-a` only shows the interfaces that are up along with their addresses (also all of IPv4, IPv6 and some link-level ones, and with a different list of extra information).

You can also tell `ip address` (short for `ip address show`) to exclude interfaces that are not up by doing:

```
ip address show up
```

(or `ip a s up` for short).

You can limit to IPv4 addresses with `-4` (and IPv6 with `-6`).

And add statistics like `ifconfig` does by default with the `-s` option.

So `ip -s a s up` would give you the same kind of information as `ifconfig` does. Remove the `up` for `ifconfig -a`.

See `man ip address` (`man ip-address`) for details.

Answer (score 3):

The command is `ip address show up` which lists only running interfaces.